# Justifing text in poster using column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, posters

In a Poster i want to justified mt text whish is in a column.
I tried searching for a solution but did not find one. Here is a minimum working example:

```
\begin{column}{.479\textwidth}
\begin{Partie}{2.Word Symmetric Functions  \vspace{-.17em}}
\textbf{2.1 Basic definitions and properties}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item A set partition of size $n$ is a set of disjoint subsets whose union is $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ (we will denote $\pi  \vDash n$).
    $$ \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}, \{ \{1\}, \{2,3\} \}, \{ \{2\}, \{1,3\} \}, \{ \{3\}, \{1, 2\} \}, \{ \{1, 2, 3\} \} $$
    \item The algebra $\WSym$ \cite{RS} is generated by $\Phi:\{\Phi^{\pi}\}$
     and $M_{\pi}$, the word power sum functions and word monomial functions,
     whose elements are indexed by set partitions of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ defined by:
     $ \Phi^{\pi} = \sum_{\substack{\pi \leqslant \pi'}} M_{\pi'} $ when $\pi 
     \leqslant \pi'$ ($\pi$ is finer than $\pi'$).  
     \item $\WSym$ is a Hopf algebra:

     \begin{itemize}
           \item The shifted concatenation product: $ \Phi^\pi\Phi^{\pi'} 
                 = \Phi^{\pi\pi'[n]} $
           \item The coproduct : $\Delta M_\pi 
                 = \sum_{\substack{\pi'\cup\pi''=\pi\\\pi'\cap\pi''=\varnothing}}
                 M_{\mathrm{std}(\pi')} \otimes M_{\mathrm{std}(\pi'')}$
     \end{itemize}
     \item The coproduct of $\WSym$ consists of identifying the algebra $\WSym 
           \otimes \WSym$ with $\WSym(\mathbb{A} + \mathbb{B})$ when $\mathbb{A}$ 
            and $\mathbb{B}$ are two non commutative alphabets \cite{HNT}.
     \end{itemize} 
\end{Partie}
\end{column}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Which document class are you using? Please complete your snippet up to a *complete* document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\justifying` from the [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package: in my example I used the `beamer` class (which internally sets the text to be `\raggedright`), but this will also work if, for example, `beamerposter` is used to produce the poster; compare the results without and with `\justifying` (notice that in narrow columns the inter-word spacing might be not optiomal with `\justifying`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text here just for demostration purposes. And some other words to fill the available space. Just some other words
\end{itemize}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item\justifying Some text here just for demostration purposes. And some other words to fill the available space. Just some other words
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want `\justifying` to be automatically applied to all your document, add to the preamble

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\let\raggedright\justifying
```

(and keep your fingers crossed).